# NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang++ isnt working

Tags: c++, android-ndk, clang, llvm

I recently read a post 
 [C++ 11 threads with clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226840/c-11-threads-with-clang)

that stated that there is a difference when compiling with clang for C and for C++. With C++ I should use clang++. I have attempted to do, but my program isnt compiling.

Here is my Application.mk

```
APP_STL := c++_shared

APP_OPTIM := debug

APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti

APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

APP_PLATFORM := android-23

APP_ABI := arm64-v8a armeabi armeabi-v7a mips mips64 x86 x86_64

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang++
```

And here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

SDL_PATH := ../SDL


LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -std=c++14 -Werror -Wall -DGLEW_NO_GLU -D_ANDROID_ -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../common/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c \
    Source.cpp Another.cpp AndAnother.cpp DontForgetAboutMe.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2 SDL2_mixer
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := freetype2-static -lc++

LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -lGLESv3 -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

How do I get clang to compile for C++?

Comment: Have you tried using just `clang`? Comments on the other thread suggests it will infer a file to be C++ from the file extension, automatically using `clang++` for those files.

Comment: yes i've used clang and it compiles well

Comment: paste actual error that you are getting. In CMake you should use include_directories() to setup include files. You do not link to all GLES versions - instead of `LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -lGLESv3 -llog` do  `target_link_libraries(EXE_NAME GLESv3 log)`